# ReferenceError: Fname is not defined in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular JS and not resolve the error i don't know what is the issue in this code. Error occurred as ReferenceError: Fname is not defined in Angular JS

```
<body ng-app="login" ng-controller="oput">
    <label>Firstname:</label><input type="text" ng-model="welcome.Fname"><br>
    <label>Lastname:</label><input type="text"  ng-model="welcome.Lname"><br>
    <button ng-click="fun()">Submit</button><br>
    <p>{{welcome.Fname}}</p>

    <script>

        var app=angular.module("login",[]);
        app.controller("oput", function($scope){
        $scope.welcome={Fname:"",
                        Lname:""}

         $scope.fun=function(){
            if(Fname == "raam" && Lname == "Chandru"){
            alert("hi raam");
         }
            else {
                alert("it is incorrect");
            }

        }

});

</script>       
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to let you know, it's unclear exactly what is going on in the example you give. Please consider editing your question to improve the formatting, and perhaps provide additional context so we can help you solve this.

Comment: Fname should be $scope.welcome.Fname

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach. I've added `$scope.welcome.variableName` to the if condition.

```
<body ng-app="login" ng-controller="oput">
    <label>Firstname:</label><input type="text" ng-model="welcome.Fname"><br>
    <label>Lastname:</label><input type="text"  ng-model="welcome.Lname"><br>
    <button ng-click="fun()">Submit</button><br>
    <p>{{welcome.Fname}}</p>

    <script>

        var app=angular.module("login",[]);
        app.controller("oput", function($scope){
        $scope.welcome={Fname:"",
                        Lname:""}

         $scope.fun=function(){
            if($scope.welcome.Fname == "raam" && $scope.welcome.Lname == "Chandru"){
            alert("hi raam");
         }
            else {
                alert("it is incorrect");
            }

        }

});

</script>       
</body>
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tnYDtdDkwDxQwKZz5Z63?p=preview)**